# include external library inside programmatically created jar

Tags: java, jar

I have a java program that is created using jaroutput stream. and the output jar uses an external library.

At first I thought that I could use classpath in the manifest to get the external library inside the jar.
Then I found out that that doesnt work.

Then I thought about custom class loaders such as one-jar.
but I got stuck trying to get it to work in a generated jar.

External library is jsonsimple 1.1.1 if you are wondering.

and here is the code for the generated custom jar.

```
    public void run(String output) throws IOException {
      Manifest manifest = new Manifest();
      manifest.getMainAttributes().put(Attributes.Name.MANIFEST_VERSION, "1.0");
      manifest.getMainAttributes().put(Attributes.Name.MAIN_CLASS, "Install");
      manifest.getMainAttributes().put(Attributes.Name.CLASS_PATH, "json-simple-1.1.1.jar");
      JarOutputStream target = new JarOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(output), manifest);
      add(tempclass, target,"Install.class");
      add(tempjar, target,"lib/json-simple-1.1.1.jar");
      if (resourcepackzip != null) {
          add(resourcepackzip, target,resourcepackzip.getName().toString()); 
      }
      if (optionstxt != null){
          add(optionstxt, target,optionstxt.getName().toString());
      }
      add(worldzip, target,worldzip.getName().toString());
      add(temptxt, target,temptxt.getName().toString());
      target.close();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    private void add(File source, JarOutputStream target,String source2) throws IOException
    {
      BufferedInputStream in = null;
      try
      {
        if (source.isDirectory())
        {
          String name = source.getPath().replace("\\", "/");
          if (!name.isEmpty())
          {
            if (!name.endsWith("/"))
              name += "/";
            JarEntry entry = new JarEntry(name);
            entry.setTime(source.lastModified());
            target.putNextEntry(entry);
            target.closeEntry();
          }
          for (File nestedFile: source.listFiles())
            add(nestedFile, target, nestedFile.getName().toString());
          return;
        }

        JarEntry entry = new JarEntry(source2);
      entry.setTime(source.lastModified());
       target.putNextEntry(entry);
        in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(source));

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while (true)
        {
          int count = in.read(buffer);
          if (count == -1)
            break;
          target.write(buffer, 0, count);
        }
      }finally {

      }
    }
```

So is there anyway I can include json in a jar made with jaroutputstream?

Comment: If you just want to create a jar with its dependancies included, you can try a build tool like `Maven` or `Gradle` for that

Comment: @SameeraB But I dont think you can use those tools to create a jar programmaticly.  I have a program that creates the jar that I want the dependancies to be included in.

Comment: So you have a scenario where the created jar is depending on the user action or something?

Comment: @SameeraB I may be dumb, but I do not understand your latest sentence. I want the dependency json simple v 1.1.1 to be inside a jar created by jaroutputstream. and the output has 1 class and that one class uses json simple. I just want it to be 1 jar.